# SQL Server Agent doesn't turn on after upgrading from SQL EXPRESS to SQL Standard

Tags: sql-server

I upgrade the `SQL 2014 Express` to a `Standard edition` without changing the instance name. There was a success and it seems to be working fine, except the `SQL AGENT`.

Error message from configuration manager:

> The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.
>   Consult the event log or other applicable error logs details.

Trying with the server administrator user. Built in account/Local service also don't work.

Event log doesn't show anything except that it's turned on and then off.

This is what I see in DETAILS. doesn't tell me anything:

> - Provider
>
>   [ Name]  SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS
>
>   - EventID 102
>
>   [ Qualifiers]  16384 
>      Level 4 
>      Task 2 
>      Keywords 0x80000000000000

Trying to run it from CMD with admin rights:

> StartServiceCtrlDispatcher failed (error 0).

Read somewhere to try to turn off VIA protocol. I don't have any protocol called VIA.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the Security log? You may be using an account that doesn't have the permission to run as a service. Normal accounts do not have this priviledge

Comment: Yes, it was really something in that area. I resolved it myself coincidentally..  Microsoft should really work on their error messages. Not everything has to be a riddle.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just after I posted I checked the security and found out that the BUILTIN\USERS didn't have sysadmin permission..

After adding it, it was resolved!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late, but I hope it helps someone in the future; a fix that has worked for me after an upgrade from Express to Standard was to run the Repair option (see image) from the Maintenance node of the SQL Server Installation Center. Once the repair completes & restart finishes, Agent works as expected.

[Use Repair option from the Maintenance page of the SQL Server Installation Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqaKz.gif)

Comment: After the repair, I also needed to go into the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool and manually "Start" the SQL Server Agent service and make sure its Start Mode was set to "Automatic".

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I upgraded the SQL Server 2017 from Express to Standard. The SQL Server Agent would not start even after the upgrade.

I an error message in the SQLAgent Log
(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017EXPRESS\MSSQL\Log)

> 2017-12-18 16:21:06 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)

Changing the SQL agent service Log On account to "Local System" does not work (as you described).

Ultimately what worked for me is changed the Log On account to "NT Service\MSSQL$SQL2017EXPRESS" works.

This user was created when I named the SQL Server "SQL2017EXPRESS" during installation. If you open up SSMS, connect to your database instance, and open up Security->Logins, you should able find a list of database NT Service users that have access the system database (msdb). Try using one of those users as your Log On user for the SQL Agent Service.

I think you install Standard edition, it would create a user call NT Service\MSSQLAgent$2014.

During research, I tried in the instruction in this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/955763/the-sql-server-agent-service-does-not-start-after-you-upgrade-from-sql). It appears using Sql Server Configuration Manager to change the Log On user didn't work for me. Instead, changing the Log On user from Administrator->View Local Services works.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with SQL 2019 after upgrading from express to standard.  Doing the Repair from the installation maintenance section fixed the agent for me.